# Incorrect url returned by plugins_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a url to my plugin, but plugins_url function returns an incorrect one.

in main plugin file there's this line:

```
$this->plugin_url     = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
```

Note, I've changed my plugins folder through `wp-config.php`:

```
...
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/home/victor/hg/' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://hg.victorpc.org' );
...
```

`hg.victorpc.org` is a vhost with document root set to `/home/victor/hg`

the function returns this URL `http://hg.victorpc.org/home/victor/hg/<plugin-folder>` and the correct is `http://hg.victorpc.org/hg/<plugin-folder>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around it, using:

```
plugins_url( basename( __DIR__ ) );
```

which returns what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plugin_dir_url()` instead.

Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url

Usage:

```
$this->plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
```

This will return: `http://hg.victorpc.org/hg/<plugin-folder>/` (notice the trailing slash).

Comment: returned url using plugin_dir_url `http://hg.victorpc.org/home/victor/hg/<plugin-folder>/`